# Node.js set variable not undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, aws-lambda

I'm trying to compile this part of code in Node.js for aws-lambda but variable `latIT` at the end is still `undefined`.

```
try {
    var urlfile ='https://url of json file';
    var data = JSON.parse(urlfile, 'utf8');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var latIT = data.results[i].geometry.location.lat;
    }
    return latIT;
} catch(error) {
    //error 
}
```

Content of json is something like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {  "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.422593,
               "lng" : -122.0853986
            }
          }
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: var latIT;
`for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     latIT = data.results[i].geometry.location.lat;
  }`

Comment: you appear to be trying to parse the string `urlfile`, which contains your URL, rather than making a HTTP request to that URL and parsing the _result of the request_. Once you get past that hurdle, you'll find that your result is an object, not an array...you probably want to put `i < data.results.length;` in your for loop's condition instead.

Comment: For the data that you have I also wouldnt even use a for loop. Just pick the first index of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through array instead of iterating through data. **In your json data.Results is an array not data**

```
//Easy implemenation
for(var temp of jsonObj.results){
  console.log(temp.geometry.location.lat);
}
```

```js
var jsonObj = {
   "results" : [
      {  "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.422593,
               "lng" : -122.0853986
            }
          }
       }
   ]
};

var latIT;
for(var temp of jsonObj.results){
  latIT = temp.geometry.location.lat;
}
console.log(latIT);
```

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I updated the answer. OP was iterating through element not an array. **Here results is an array not data**

Comment: ok, fair enough. (I actually just realised the problem myself before reading your edit, and posted it as an answer myself.)

Comment: But first, the data is undefined because the code is trying to parse a string containing a URL, not the _result of a HTTP request to that URL_. But yes, once we actually obtain a result then you're absolutely right about the data structure.

Comment: @ADyson, I agree with your point. I wrote answer based on json provided by OP

Comment: Oh thanks guys, sorry is my first time with node. So i think my real problem is to obtain results from url json mmm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `data` variable has the same shape as the JSON you posted, your error is referring to `data.length`, when the object has no such property. Arrays automatically have a `length` property, but `data` here is an object, not an array. It appears that you meant to check on `data.results.length` instead. (`data.results` *is* an array, and this appears to be what you are iterating over.)

Comment: "Assuming the data variable has..." the data is undefined because the code is trying to parse a string containing a URL, not the _result of a HTTP request to that URL_. Aside from that, your point is entirely valid once the OP has actually obtained a result.

Comment: @ADyson - you're right, I had missed that in the OP, but did see your comment (and upvoted it). I'll leave this here because I feel it is still relevant (unless the community disagrees by downvoting it), but you're right that it isn't the first error to fix.

Comment: @ADyson can you help me to result of a HTTP request to that URL? Thanks

Comment: @Lorenz did you try to google "nodeJS make http request", maybe?